# How to fix AutoValidateMode issue on Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am making an app for Phone Authentication with Firebase and Flutter. I am not using any form field but I am getting error of `AutoValidateMode` Not Found. I have been looking for solution on net since 2 days but couldn't able to find one. The code is as follow.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sms_autofill/sms_autofill.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Phone Auth'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  final TextEditingController _phoneNumberController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _smsController = TextEditingController();
  String _verificationId;
  final SmsAutoFill _autoFill = SmsAutoFill();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(
                    controller: _phoneNumberController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Phone number (+xx xxx-xxx-xxxx)'),
                  ),],
              )),
        ));
  }
}
```

For this code, I am getting error as follow.

```
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pin_input_text_field-3.3.0/lib/src/widget/pin_widget.dart:402:5: Error: Type 'AutovalidateMode' not found.
    AutovalidateMode autovalidateMode = AutovalidateMode.disabled,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pin_input_text_field-3.3.0/lib/src/widget/pin_widget.dart:402:5: Error: 'AutovalidateMode' isn't a type.
    AutovalidateMode autovalidateMode = AutovalidateMode.disabled,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pin_input_text_field-3.3.0/lib/src/widget/pin_widget.dart:402:41: Error: Getter not found: 'AutovalidateMode'.
    AutovalidateMode autovalidateMode = AutovalidateMode.disabled,
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pin_input_text_field-3.3.0/lib/src/widget/pin_widget.dart:436:13: Error: No named parameter with the name 'autovalidateMode'.
            autovalidateMode: autovalidateMode,
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How to fix this issue? Where to edit `AutoValidateMode` to always?
Your help is very grateful.

Comment: I suspect you're using https://pub.dev/packages/pin_input_text_field and it is probably already written expecting the new protocol for AutovalidateMode.  You'll probably need to clone the package and see where the change was made, and put that as an upper bound in your pubspec.yaml.

Comment: Ok... I will try this also. I read something else on github that upgrading to flutter version 1.22 fixed the issue. I will try your suggestion as well. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @RandalSchwartz. The issue is solved by upgrading flutter to 1.22

Answer (score 0):

Going through the error, it mentioned that it can't find the AutoValidateMode that's being used. It looks like `AutoValidateMode` was released on Flutter 1.22 stable and isn't available on versions prior. This is documented on the [Breaking Changes page](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/form-field-autovalidation-api). Updating to the latest Flutter version should solve the issue.